# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"../proc/insur.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{carmodel:carmodel,usage:usage,mk:mk,sdate:startdate},
        processData: false,
        error: function() {
            alert("fialed");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#insurance').html(data);
        }
    });
```

I also tried the code below, but my values were not sent

```
processData: false
```

what can i do?

Comment: I think the data should be stringified?

Comment: remove this  `processData: false` it should work

Comment: If set to false it stops jQuery processing any of the data. In other words if processData is false jQuery simply sends whatever you specify as data in an Ajax request without any attempt to modify it by encoding as a query string

Comment: It might be misspelled of `var` in `data` please check your `carmodel` and other variable too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass strings. Use [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for your data.

```
let data = JSON.stringify({carmodel:carmodel,usage:usage,mk:mk,sdate:startdate});
```